# angular preview image - cannot set property 'photo' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

working on a preview image code but can not sort it out due to some issue

view:

```
<img ng-src="{[vm.photo]}"/>
<input type="file" on-add-image="uploadFile"/>
```

directive:

```
.directive('onAddImage', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          var onImgChange = scope.$eval(attrs.onAddImage);
          element.bind('change', onImgChange);
        }
      };
    });
```

controller:

```
    var vm = this;

    $scope.uploadFile = function() {

        dietImage = event.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(event) {
            vm.photo = event.target.result
            $scope.$apply()
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    };
```

error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'photo' of undefined at FileReader.reader.onload"

Comment: no we have set it the way it is so that's not a problem

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem could be the ControllerAs syntax ..cause i don't see how you bind your vm of controller to HTML...

try something like:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm">
<img ng-src="{[vm.photo]}"/>
<input type="file" on-add-image="uploadFile"/>
</div>
```

or better put in your routing file (app.config) your `controllerAs: 'vm'`

Comment: it added within routes controller: 'myControllerCtrl', controllerAs: 'vm'

Comment: have you also put in your directive .. $scope.apply(function(){ element.bind('change', onImgChange); })